# Why does the DCGAN output degrade with an increase in the kernel size?

Tags: neural-networks, keras, gan

Thank you for the explanation on the kernel size.
I have been experimenting with the sample Generative Adversarial Network (GAN) code from the book on Deep learning with Python by François Chollet, Section 8.5.3 Page 308. I noticed that when I happen to increase the kernel size in the keras.layers.Conv2D function, the output of the generator model degrades while decreasing the kernel size improves the performance of the generator. Could you help me in better understanding this?

Answer (score 1):

By decreasing the size of the convolutional kernel, you're changing the number of parameters in the model (as well as what scales it looks at the data in). The optimization process for models like DCGAN is somewhat unstable, not super well-understood, and needs a very careful balance between the generator and discriminator; especially if you change one and not the other, it could throw all kinds of things off in the ability to actually optimize the model.